# Torque in a stone

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, torque, free-body-diagram, string

If force is applied tangentially where does centripetal acceleration comes from because it is directed toward center and force applied is tangential?

Answer (score 1):

The centripetal force on a piece of a stone is provided by internal forces that keep the stone together. Essentially, the chemical bonds in the stone act as small springs that hold it together.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72928/discussion-on-answer-by-probably-someone-torque-in-a-stone).